# Error on environment.rb file under config (Ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email

Below is my environment.rb file

```
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

Wiyo::Application.initialize!

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "example.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: 'atomambition@gmail.com',
  password: '********'
}
```

I have put my gmail password in ****** section. But when i do rake:db migrate, it shows error on environment.rb file telling me

> 7:in '>'.

Please help me. I am creating mailing function in my rails app. I am stuck.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is nothing wrong with the code you've supplied as far as I can tell. Please post the actual error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration code should **not** be included in `environments.rb`. The `config` global is localized to the *environment specific* configuration files found within `config/environments`. Try adding this code to the appropriate file there:

```
# config/environment/development.rb
Wiyo:::Application.configure do

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "example.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: 'atomambition@gmail.com',
    password: '********'
  }

  # remainder of configuration

end
```

Comment: So? Did you try my recommendation?

Comment: I solved the problem. I kepet that information on development.rb. Thank you

Comment: Please accept this answer as correct by clicking the check mark underneath the answer's score, then. This signals that the answer was helpful in addressing your issue.